# SQL mulitple column join and rename or map joined columns - faster single query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables:

[Nodes]

```
row_index | obj_index    | obj_name    | obj_age | other | type
0         | 1450         | dog         | 2.7     | 943   | animal
1         | 2954         | cat         | 3.5     | 20    | animal
2         | 5613         | train       | 1.8     | 540   | vehicle
3         | 7852         | mouse       | 4.3     | 2     | animal
4         | 2380         | money       | 3.2     | 12    | currency
5         | 6341         | jetta       | 1.8     | 40    | vehicle
```

[Edges]

```
row_index | obj1_index   | obj2_index  | edge_prop 
0         | 1450         | 2954        | 18
1         | 2954         | 5613        | 1
2         | 2380         | 6341        | 3
3         | 5613         | 6341        | 56
4         | 1450         | 7852        | 26
5         | 2380         | 7852        | 6
6         | 7852         | 2954        | 7
7         | 6341         | 2954        | 9
```

The output I am trying to get is this:

```
obj1_index | obj2_index | edge_prop | obj_name_x | obj_age_x | obj_name_y | obj_age_y
1450       | 2954       | 18        | dog        | 2.7       | cat        | 3.5
7852       | 2954       | 7         | mouse      | 4.3       | cat        | 3.5
6341       | 2954       | 9         | jetta      | 1.8       | cat        | 3.5
1450       | 7852       | 26        | dog        | 2.7       | mouse      | 4.3
2954       | 5613       | 1         | cat        | 3.5       | train      | 1.8
5613       | 6341       | 56        | train      | 1.8       | jetta      | 1.8
```

Essentially, I would like to get the edges between certain nodes with a given property, so the inside query may be:

```
SELECT * FROM Nodes WHERE type IS IN 'animal' OR 'vehicle'
```

and then a major problem comes in joining this along the both the `obj1` and `obj2` index, and naming the columns...

This is the SQL Statment I have tried to work with, but it isn't correct - and is likely exceedingly slow due to having to run the inside query twice (the sqlite database is only few billion rows, but it would still be nice to have some performance):

```
SELECT E.*, N1.object_name AS obj_name_2, N2.object_name AS obj_name_2 FROM Edges E 
  INNER JOIN (
      SELECT * FROM Nodes
      WHERE type IN ('animal', 'vehicle')) AS N1
  ON (E.obj1_index = N1.obj_index AND E.obj2_index = N1.obj_index)
  INNER JOIN (
      SELECT * FROM Nodes
      WHERE type IN ('animal', 'vehicle')) AS N2
  ON (E.obj2_index = N2.obj_index AND E.obj2_index = N2.obj_index)
```

But it does not work.

Any suggestions for a better SQL query for this?

The tables strings in csv are below, since the above is not a preferred data structure best suited to try out things in SQL:

Nodes:

```
,row_index,obj_index,obj_name,obj_age,other,type\n0,0,1450,dog,2.7,943,animal\n1,1,2954,cat,3.5,20,animal\n2,2,5613,train,1.8,540,vehicle\n3,3,7852,mouse,4.3,2,animal\n4,4,2380,money,3.2,12,currency\n5,5,6341,jetta,1.8,40,vehicle\n
```

Edges:

```
,row_index,obj1_index,obj2_index,edge_prop\n0,0,1450,2954,18\n1,1,2954,5613,1\n2,2,2380,6341,3\n3,3,5613,6341,56\n4,4,1450,7852,26\n5,5,2380,7852,6\n6,6,7852,2954,7\n7,7,6341,2954,9\n
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want two joins:

```
select e.*, n1.*, n2.*
from edges e join
     nodes n1
     on e.obj1_index = n1.obj_index join
     nodes n2
     on e.obj2_index = n2.obj_index
where n1.type in ('animal', 'vehicle') and
      n2.type in ('animal', 'vehicle') ;
```